# Weird behaviour of two option set field in the BPF

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

I'm facing one weird problem on the Contact entity. I do have one check box type field on the Contact form. When user selects (ticks) this checkbox at that time I'm making one field as mandatory in the BPF. This is a two options (yes/no) field on the BPF.

The problem is when on click of the checkbox on the form, the BPF field displays "click to enter" text, not sure why it is showing this text on the field.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: That’s the product behavior. Is that your question?

Comment: Is it displaying click to enter text for the check box?  I've seen a couple v9 bugs revolving around the BPF not displaying the correct helper text.  Submit it as a bug to MS.